# SpriteKit Detect Ranges

Tags: sprite-kit

I am making small/mid RTS game, I have the following need:

I want Enemy Players to Attack allies and vice versa when they are in each attack range.

My question is: what would be a better approach finding if enemy units are in attack range of allied or vice versa of course ?

What have I tried:

For now I tried to add `SKNodes` with `SKPhysicsBodies` for each unit Node.

I can see that FPS are going down when the contact happens... I guess it wasn't the best way to know detect whether enemies are in range.

I guess my alternative is to run some Nested Loop within Update method and check if there are enemy units within the Radius. 
I am not sure if it is the best approach, however with this approach I may play with some parameters and maybe optimize the routine for my own needs.

I would like to know if there is some better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into GamePlayKit,

It may have some things you want.

Otherwise I would just use the Euclidiean Distance Formula https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139600/euclidean-manhattan-distance without the square root,  and use this value based on  squads, not individual troops.  (So if a group of 4 soldiers is attacking an enemy of 5 soldiers, only 1 distance check is done).

The reason why you do not square root, is because you should know the squared allowable distance.  If an enemy 10 pixels away attracts soldiers, then use 100.

The best way to treat your soldiers like squads,  add them all to an SKNode  (sub class to add better functionality),  then you just need to compare those squad SKNodes

If you want to reduce the number of checks you make,  consider turning your play area into a grid (Like a chess board).  Since you know the size of your tiles, you could easily check to see if the units are close enough to warrant a distance check.  E.G.  You have a unit at a1, and an enemy at i9, then you know just by tile distance that the units are too far apart to attack each other

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I have some struggles using Squads for allied units (I allow user to fully control the units one by one or dynamic formations).
Enemy units are indeed going by fixed squads.

Thanks for the distance suggestions

Comment: you just keep a stack of squad nodes handy,  and use the `moveToParent` method to swap between them

Comment: I guess it just doesn't fit my gameplay (I want to achieve unit control like it was in Myth2 game). In any case I implemented most of your suggestion. I checking for each alied unit how far is it from enemy squad, if in range then he attacks who ever is in enemy squad. I call this check on a background thread from the - update method... however if I am not using Shield Window approach the fps are about 40 and I have only 11 units 1 friendly and 10 enemies in 1 squad :-(

Comment: no idea what you are talking about,  i watched some videos, they are definitely forming squads,  you can have a squad of one unit

Comment: you do not want to be calling this stuff on a background thread,  you have no idea when it could execute

Comment: 11 units searching 10 enemies means 110 times you call your distance formula,  you need to reduce these numbers

Comment: I tried it before, but I came to conclusion (maybe faulty) that when user selects bunch of units and commands them to move, I am building a ghost squad (units are not its children) that calculates positions and rotations and then I command every unit to go for its suitable position.

Comment: you shouldn't move all units,  you should only move the center of the group, and give the illusion they are all moving

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing for the enemies (AI)

Comment: also consider setting up a tile playfield,  then you can reduce some work,  like if an enemy is at 1a, and your guy is at 9i, you know to ignore calculating distance

Comment: Yeah thats a great Idea I should defenitelly implement a navmesh

Comment: Sir, is it really better to go back and try to rebuild the User controlled units to be binded to squads ?

Comment: if you want to have a lot going on I would

Comment: Also could you add a navmesh approach to your answer? the. I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: its not really a navmesh lol  navmesh is for things like avoiding terrain and stuff

Comment: yes, you could use a navmesh to also find your enemy,  it is just a more advance feature.  I am almost positive Gameplay Kit could handle something like this

Comment: I am not sure, the closest thing I found is a GKGraph used for pathfinding :-:

Comment: Yes, I planned to use it, and now I am confused a bit, If i am about to move all units as a single squad it could be a problem navigating through out tiny areas

Comment: provie?  what is that

Comment: you would need to handle the tiny areas as well,  but it is easier and less resource intensive to handle it on a need to change basis